# array in loop in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

I try to make a pseudo array in bash

```
    frame1=(one two three)
    frame2=(one two three)
    frame3=(one two three)
    echo ${frame2[2]}
```

works but

```
for ((fr=1; fr<=$records; fr++)) 
do
frame$fr=(one two three)
done
```

doesn't work. How to make a pseudo array like that in bash ?

[edit]
if I try to use the variable in the inside loop it doesn't work

```
for ((fr=0; fr<=$records; fr++))
do
declare -a "frame$fr=(one two three)"
done
for ((fr=0; fr<=$records; fr++))
do
for ((lv=0; lv<=$fields; lv++))
do
#echo ${frame$fr[2]}
echo ${frame6[$lv]}
done
done
```

the above works but the line that is commented out does not work it says

```
line 16: ${frame$fr[2]}: bad substitution
```

Comment: Re: your edit. You must use indirect expansion. Btw, Bash is not exactly supposed to work like this, with simili-pointers. Leave that for other programming languages and review your design. Now if you _really_ want to do this, `name=frame$fr[$lv]; echo "${!name}"` will do.

Comment: I just try to get the fields (images) from a spreadsheet with awk and send them to an array and then to imagemagick. would you call #!/bin/awk a language ? can I send to imagemagick from awk ? otherwise what language would you suggest as I think I will get in trouble this way because I still have to put real values in the array.

Comment: You could try with Perl, as it has nice bindings for ImageMagick, and you'll be able to do arrays of arrays without problems. Python would be okay too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `declare` builtin to evaluate the LHS to a name first.

```
for ((f1=1; f2<=$records; fr++))
do
  declare -a "frame$fr=(one two three)"
done
```